# What Is The Weakest Possible Encryption Algorithm

Tags: symmetric, algorithm-design

I've been creating a Capture The Flag site and for one of the challenges I wanted you to have to break an encryption algorithm. Granted I want it to be a weak one, so I want the weakest out there. One that needs a password and it's a symmetrical key encryption. One that could be cracked in 20 minutes or less with minimal work.

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a [vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).  For example,

```
let ciphertext = "this is my msg!!" + "passwordpassword"
[0xe4, 0xc9, 0xdc, 0xe6, 0x97, 0xd8, 0xe5, 0x84, 0xdd, 0xda, 0x93,
 0xe0, 0xea, 0xd6, 0x93, 0x85]
```

It's hard to get simpler than this.  The password is the key - the only key expansion step needed is to repeat the key over and over.  The encryption algorithm is addition (optionally: use XOR) the decryption algorithm is subtraction (optionally: use XOR).

Another option is to use [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

```
Cryptol> let alphabet = ['a'..'z'] # " "
Cryptol> let ciphertext = [alphabet @ ((c-'a'+key) % 27)
                              | c <- "this is my message"]
                          where key = 't'
Cryptol> ciphertext
"apq yq yufyum  iom"
```